# Custom control picker bindable selected item don't work at the initialisation

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, binding, custom-controls

I got an issue when trying to create a custom control with a picker inside.
I create a bindable property

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty PhoneCodeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PhoneCode),
            typeof(PhoneIndex),
            typeof(PhoneEntry),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: PhoneCodePropertyChanged);

private static void PhoneCodePropertyChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
      PhoneEntry control = (PhoneEntry)bindable;

      control.Picker.SelectedItem = newValue ?? oldValue;
      Console.WriteLine($"Picker Value => {control.Picker.SelectedItem}");

}

public PhoneIndex PhoneCode
{
      get => (PhoneIndex)GetValue(PhoneCodeProperty);

      set => SetValue(PhoneCodeProperty, value);
}
```

Then I populate my picker and set the value that I want to show first in the constructor of my control :

```cs
phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.GetInstance();
var callingcode = phoneNumberUtil.GetSupportedRegions();


PhoneCodesStrings = new List<PhoneIndex>();

foreach (string CountryCode in callingcode)
{
      PhoneCodesStrings.Add(new PhoneIndex(CountryCode, phoneNumberUtil.GetCountryCodeForRegion(CountryCode)));
}

PhoneCodesStrings.Sort(CompareByCountryCode);
Picker.ItemsSource = PhoneCodesStrings;
Predicate<PhoneIndex> predicate = IsFr;

Picker.SelectedIndexChanged += Picker_SelectedIndexChanged;
Entry.TextChanged += Entry_TextChanged;

PhoneCode = PhoneCodesStrings.Find(predicate);
```

And after this I call my control like that :

```xml
<controls:PhoneEntry
                    Margin="0,8,0,0"
                    PhoneCode="{Binding CurrentIndex}"
                    PhoneNumber="{Binding CurrentPhoneNumber}"
                    ValidPhoneNumber="{Binding ValidPhoneNumber}" />
```

My picker is set OK, I can see it with any problem in my UI, but I don't get any value in my viewmodel until the user change the value of the picker

Does anyone know why ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: @EhsanVali Phonecode is set here `PhoneCode = PhoneCodesStrings.Find(predicate);` to use a predicate to locate a specific element in a list ( this is in the constructor of my control ) and then the picker property is set with `control.Picker.SelectedItem = newValue ?? oldValue;` that is trigger when phonecode change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my problem is solved and it was the binding mode that cause my issue. I set it to onewaytosource and then it was ok

Comment: Please  mark your reply as answered.  Thanks in advance.  :)

Answer (score 0):

you want to set a default value for a bindableproperty.
you must set it to [defaultValueCreator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties#create-a-default-value-with-a-func) parameter.

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PhoneCodeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(PhoneCode),
            typeof(PhoneIndex),
            typeof(PhoneEntry),
            defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanged: PhoneCodePropertyChanged
            defaultValueCreator: PhoneCodeDefaultValue);

public static PhoneIndex PhoneCodeDefaultValue(BindableObject bindable)
{
           PhoneCodesStrings = new List<PhoneIndex>();

           foreach (string CountryCode in callingcode)
           {
                PhoneCodesStrings.Add(new PhoneIndex(CountryCode,phoneNumberUtil.GetCountryCodeForRegion(CountryCode)));
           }
           Predicate<PhoneIndex> predicate = IsFr;
           return PhoneCodesStrings.Find(predicate);
 }
```